# How can I use Cypress to check the text of an element's event?

Tags: cypress

There is an html document that contains the following snippet:

```html
<li class="test">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getVal('101')"></a>
</li>
```

I want to use Cypress check if the onclick text is "getVal('101')".

What I have tried is:

```js
cy.get('li.test').each(($el, index) => {
    cy.wrap($el)
    .its('onclick')
    .then(content => {
        console.log(content);
    });
});
```

But, that does not work. I also tried:

```js
cy.get('li.test').each(($el, index) => {
    cy.wrap($el)
    .invoke('attr', 'onclick')
    .then((onclick) => {
        console.log(onclick);
    });
});
```

But, that did not work either. How can I get the "text" of an event?

Comment: Not sure about cypress, but from your example code, you seem to be selecting the wrapped `li` element and not the `a` one with the onclick attr. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: It might be better to have this kind of check as a component test to spy/stub.

Comment: What makes you think it's not a component test? The code is the same either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.its()` command is for accessing property values, but in the HTML `onclick` is an attribute.

Also, it's on the `<a>` element, so you will need to add that into the selector.

Try this instead

```js
cy.get('li.test a')
  .each(($el, index) => {
    cy.wrap($el)
      .then($el => $el.attr('onclick'))  // extract the attribute
      .then(console.log)
  })
```